# Downloading an Excel file over https to IE from a J2EE application

Tags: excel, jakarta-ee, internet-explorer

Is there a way to download an Excel file from a J2EE application to an IE browser over https.  My code works fine with Mozilla but IE just gives an error.  I know that Excel over https is a problem for IE.  While I've seen solutions for some environments, I haven't seen anything for J2EE.

jd

Comment: Any details on the error? Any pointers to the problem you are referring too? This would help readers a bit in my opinion.

Comment: which version(s) of IE, and what is the error? Known issues: don't send no-cache headers - old IE versions need to cache it as the browser launches apps (e.g. Excel) and points Excel to load the file from the cache.

Comment: That's almost certainly the problem: http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/02/Internet-Explorer-cannot-download-over-HTTPS-when-no-cache.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The following code fixed the issue for me in IE8.

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "private");     
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 1);
```